# Flask-Login using Radius

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am trying to setup Flask-Login where the user database is on a RADIUS server.
I can validate credentials just fine against it, but most online examples use SQLAlchemy. Do I still need to use SQLAlchemy if I am not using my own database for Flask?

I am getting errors when the User(Mixin) class is ran.

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active'`

My User class is simple since I do not need have my own DB, just need the 4 methods from the docs.

```
class User(UserMixin):
    pass
```

Here is some code for trying this just with a dictionary as the DB:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect
from forms import LoginForm
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user

users_db = {'user1': 'pass1'}

app = Flask(__name__)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    if user_id in users_db:
        print('user found in DB')
        return user_id
    else:
        return None

class User(UserMixin):
    pass


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc123'


@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def Login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('validated')
        username = form.username.data
        login_user(username)
        next = flask.request.args.get('next')
        if not is_safe_url(next):
            return flask.abort(400)
        return flask.redirect(next or flask.url_for('hi'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/hi')
def hi():
    return """<h1>Hi</h1>
           {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
               Hi {{ current_user.name }}!
           {% endif %}"""    

@app.route('/secure')
@login_required
def secure():
    return "This is a secure page."  

@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect('https://cisco.com')
```

What would be obviously wrong here, or what could I be conceptually not understanding?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your user_db only contains strings. You have to create an instance of the User class and return the instance on login.

See https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

PS I am on mobile, if this is not enough info, I'll update my answer later.

This article also introduces the login mechanism
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins

Comment: Ok, I'm still trying to figure out how I would make the User class without all the SQL stuff. I though dropping in the UserMixin would be enough.

Comment: It is! :-) But you need to use the user class. ie `john = User()` and then you need to put `john` in your dictionary. But obviously your user class would need e.g. an id and a password attribute or whatever you want to query later on.

Comment: This has to be close! Still getting the same error though! --> [Changes](https://i.imgur.com/psntQ3R.png)

Comment: You'll make it! :-)